# Selling IAP currency (for Android/iOS Apps) outside of the app stores

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase

We offer a free app with IAP. The IAP is a means to purchase curreny for our app, which then you can use have some benefits in our game. Those credits are stored in our database and not somewhere on google or apple servers. We use the IAP mechanism just for billing.

We are offering our app in a country where not everybody has his Google Play / Apple App Store associated with a credit card and not everybody uses a bank account. So a lot of our users emailed ous asking us, if they could obtain in app credits from in a different way. e.g. PayPal from our Website, sending cash in mail.

So what are the guidelines selling in app credits for an app outside of the app stores?

We developed two plans, please let me know if any of them would be possible and follow the google and apple guidelines. Both of the plans do not trigger any IAP mechanism, so in no way Apple or Google would even know what we are doing without checking our website.

Plan A:
User goes to our website, buys a promo code for e.g. 500 credits.
Opens the app and triggers a menu item specifically to redeem those codes.
Upon inserting the code, he gets credited with the credits.
The good thing about it would be, that ppl could buy codes and give them to other ppl or we could issue free promo codes over our facebook account.

Plan B:
User goes to our website, upon providing his account details, he pays for the credits which would be immediately credited to his account.

Would any of these plans be against apple/google guidelines? What could we do different to honor the guidelines and not get our app banned?

We also plan to develop a Facebook/Web App, so buying credits should not be limited to app store apps anyway.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in regards to terms and conditions of payment mechanisms in distribution channels, not programming.

Comment: in my opinion it would be good if stackoverflow would cover those aspects as well and it is not like my question is the only question regarding terms and conditions on stackoverflow

Comment: There should be another section for this kind of questions. When I search questions based on the tag "ios", I expect to find only technical questions.

Comment: "in my opinion it would be good if stackoverflow would cover those aspects as well" -- this has [already been discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic). "it is not like my question is the only question regarding terms and conditions on stackoverflow" -- those others should be close-voted as well. If you have questions on licensing terms, hire qualified legal counsel.

Comment: Very good and interesting question. I am asking myself the exactly same. I wanna offer an Adfree Version and same as you I store this information in an own database, so i can set this up on my own :)

I think the most safest way is to simply SELL the exact SAME game under a different Package name and you offer an Adfree experience for this NEW game which is technically the same as in Google Play (cons is here User cant get automatic Updates, however, you can let the Adfree stuff being swapped in the regulare game. Thats literally hard to impossible to track down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guidelines are very clean about this. Probably Apple does not notice that you have your own purchase system, but are you willing to base your business on a risk that one day you app will be removed from the App Store?

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

Comment: I believe this has been removed now, no? https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: The current version of policy says. Item 3.1.1: "If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app ... you must use in-app purchase. ... Apps and their metadata may not include buttons, external links, or other calls to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than in-app purchase." -- it's still NOT CLEAR if we can sell OUTSIDE the app. After all, we sell the same items on both Android and iOS and this is NOT A PROBLEM. What this different from web sell?